# KVM/QEMU Extra mouse features

Tags: windows, qemu, linux-kvm, libvirt, virt-manager

I have Windows 11 VM running on a Debian host. I am using virt-manager to configure and use the VM.

Does anyone know how to get the mouse back/forward buttons and horizontal scroll to work when connected to the VM using spice?

Comment: As a workaround for *horizontal scrolling* try using `Shift` with *vertical scrolling*